# Emails migrating when changing server and DNS

Tags: email, server, dns, hosting, cpanel

Hello all I am going to point my website to another server, but currently I have email accounts and I don't want to lose any old email when migrating to another server.
I googled and I found this https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204405444/how-do-i-migrate-email-between-servers-using-imap
I will open the same email accounts with same name in new cPanel, but just want to ask if I directly re-register the incoming server in my phones gmail app, will the old emails disappear?
Should I follow all the steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jason Lee

**Just follow the steps below :**

**Option 1:**

Take full cPanel backup from your current cPanel server and import in new cPanel server by following the steps below . That will migrate not only your files but also your email accounts with all your emails.

> https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9365/2199/how-to-create-and-restore-backups-in-cpanel

**Option 2:**

As you said create accounts freshly in new server.And for your query don't worry its not needed to re-register in mobile . just reconfigure your existing account in mobile that will only fetch new mails keeping existing.

*Hope this answers your query :-) Feel free to ping here in comment if any further clarifications needed*

Comment: Thank for helping! I didn't think of backing up the whole server as I used FTP every time...Now I can go ahead:)

Comment: Happy that it helped you. Kindly upvote my answer by clicking the Upward arrow which lies left to this answer, if you find it useful. :-)